# flutter pusher cant trigger event

Tags: flutter, pusher

trying to trigger event data but get this error
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot trigger event client-MessageCreated because channel private-Message.User.3.Doctor.10 is in INITIAL state"

````
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    String token = getToken();
    PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
      host: 'https://i3mal.com',
      wsPort: 6001,
      encrypted: false,
      cluster: "eu",
      auth: PusherAuth(
        'https://i3mal.com/broadcasting/auth',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      ),
    );

    pusher = PusherClient("****************", options, autoConnect: false);

    channel = pusher.subscribe("private-Message.User.3.Doctor.10");

    pusher.onConnectionStateChange((state) {

      print(
          "previousState: ${state?.previousState}, currentState: ${state?.currentState}");
    });

    pusher.onConnectionError((error) {
      print("pusher_error: ${error?.message}");
    });

    channel.bind('MessageCreated', (event) {
      print(" QQQ ");
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) => print(" QQQ "));
  } ```


    
`` void _sendMessage() async {
        try {
          await channel.trigger('MessageCreated', {"name": "Bob"});
        } catch (e) {
          print("error $e");
        }
      } ```
````